# How to close html5 video and flash alternative without it sometimes playing audio in the background?

Tags: jquery, video

Sometimes when I click on the "close" button( before the video loads up) the audio of the video still plays in the background? I am closing the video with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    var a = $
    a("img").click(function() {
    a("#trailer").fadeOut(300)
        a("video").remove();
```

more code:

```
<div id="trailer">
<img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close" />
<div id="video">
<video controls  autoplay="autoplay" poster="video/trailer.jpg" width="600"  onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();">
<source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="video/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<embed src="video/flashfox.swf" width="600" height="480"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=trailer.mp4" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

EDIT

Code doesn't work in this segment.

```
    a("#trailerb").click(function() {
        a("video")[0].pause().remove();
        a("#trailer").show("50");
        a("#video").load("video.html");
```

What should happen is on click any video playing, pauses and removes from view, then a fresh new video pops us from the .load method: here is the code from the video.html

```
<video controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay" poster="video/trailer.jpg" width="600"  height=""  onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();">
<source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="video/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<embed src="video/flashfox.swf" width="600" height="480"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=trailer.mp4" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
</video>
```

At the moment clicking on "#trailerb" only pauses any video playing, without executing:

```
a("#trailer").show("50");
a("#video").load("video.html");
```

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

For all videos:
a("video").each(function () { this.pause() });

or

for a specific instance:
a('video')[0].pause();

Insert the before the remove() action.

As per my comment:

You are trying to load the new video into  - try:

```
$('#video video').load();
```

or javascript:

```
video.src = 'video/trailer.mp4';
video.load();
video.play();
```

Comment: @ Fraccus Code doesn't work in this segment. see the edit Thanks!!

Comment: That's an entirely different problem to the first issue - but will try and answer.

Comment: You are trying to load the new video into <div id="video"> - try:

    $('#video video').load();

or javascript:

   video.src = 'video/trailer.mp4';
   video.load();
   video.play();